# Book about fluid dynamics

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, textbook-recommendation, fluid-dynamics

Next Monday, I'll have an interview at Siemens for an internship where I have to know about fluid dynamics/computational fluid dynamics. I'm not a physicist, so does somebody have a suggestion for a good book where I can read about some basics? Thank you very much.

Comment: Acheson, Elementary Fluid Dynamics. http://books.google.com/books?id=GgC69-WUTs0C

Comment: It strikes me as a bad idea to try to learn fluid dynamics in one week. But for a short account that is mathematically somewhat rigorous (that's why you are asking here on MO, right?), try Chorin and Marsden's "A Mathematical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics".

Comment: The Feynman Lectures has a couple of chapters on this.

Comment: To add to @Willie's comment: in my extensive experience with both sides of the table, it is much better to admit ignorance than to try to fake it (which is what you will be doing after learning about the subject in a couple of days).

Answer (score 4):

For the records:

Fluid Dynamics:

G.K. Batchelor, **An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics**, Cambridge, 2000.

Computational Fluid Dynamics:

John D. Anderson Jr., **Computational Fluid Dynamics - The Basics with Applications**, McGraw-Hill, 1995.

From Preface:

> This computational fluid dynamics (CFD) book is *truly for beginners*. If you have never worked in this area, and if you have no real idea as to what the discipline is all about, then this book is for you. Absolutely no prior knowledge of CFD is assumed on your part--only your desire to learn something about the subject is taken for granted.

Also, if you have access to Elsevier:  J. Tu, G. Y. and C. Liu, [Computational Fluid Dynamics - A Practical Approach](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780750685634), Elsevier, 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this [CFD crash course](http://learncfd.blogspot.com/2012/04/cfd-crash-course.html) and also [A crash course in fluid mechanics](http://www.dicca.unige.it/bottaro/fm_files/Course_FM_LaSpezia.pdf) could help a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is for a job interview, I would focus on the more applied side of computational fluid dynamics (CFD). I really liked [CFD Python: 12 steps to Navier-Stokes](https://lorenabarba.com/blog/cfd-python-12-steps-to-navier-stokes/)

A brief description of this course from the author's webpage is:

> The course is for beginners. It assumes only basic programming skills —the concepts of iterations, function calls, and so on— and builds immediate hands-on experience via this module and several others that come after.

Hope this helps others in need of a crash course on applied CFD.